# How to simulate mouse text selection?

Tags: extjs, gxt

I am using GWT/GXT. i am using Editable Grid. it has 3 columns. if user navigates from first column to other column using TAB then the text in the column should be selected as below(cell with blue background only for text not for entire cell) so that i can easily delete the text of the cell using Delete or backspace buttons with out selecting the text again. here my question is how to simulate mouse text selection?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/form/TextField.html#setSelectOnFocus%28boolean%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>();
text.setSelectOnFocus(true);
column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text));
configs.add(column); //ColumnConfig
```